# Changing Recovery Model in Replicated Database

Tags: windows, sql-server, replication

I now am the proud owner of two servers that replicate with each other.  I had nothing to do with the install, but (of course), now i have to support the databases.  Both databases are in the Simple recovery model, but the users want to ensure as little data loss as possible so I'm thinking that I should change the recovery model over to full and start doing transaction log backups.
I wasn't planning on backing up the subscribing database, only the publisher.  Is this the right plan?

Do I need to switch both the Subscriber and and the publisher to Full, or can I leave the subscriber in Simple, but have the Publisher in Full?

When I change the recovery model in one (or both) do the databases need to be offline?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no issue. recovery model will not impact Transaction replication.

Comment: Vinay, thanks for participating in Stackoverflow! Had to remove the signature from your posts. Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow